# Multiple Docker Instances: "Rootless" AND "Rootful" Docker on the same machine?

Tags: docker, rootless

I am looking for a solution for a rootless Docker instance on a machine that is already running regular Docker. Ideally, lower privileged users that do not have root access could then still use the "Rootless" Docker

There are a bunch of guides on how to install "rootless" Docker, but I haven't really found anything on the compatibility of these two. The official Docs recommend uninstalling any running Docker instance or disabling it. Can you actually have both working separately on the same server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least on Ubuntu 22.04 it seems I'm able to run both rootful and rootless Docker in parallel without issues. I set up rootless Docker as described on https://rootlesscontaine.rs/getting-started/docker/ and https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/ :

```
dockerd-rootless-setuptool.sh install
systemctl --user start docker.service
```

Notably, I did *not* run

```
sudo systemctl disable --now docker.service docker.socket
```

I.e. if I execute `sudo systemctl status docker.service docker.socket` and `systemctl status --user docker.service`, I see two Docker daemons running in parallel. Now, to choose which Docker daemon should be used, I either set

```
export DOCKER_HOST="unix:///var/run/docker.sock"  # rootful
```

or

```
export DOCKER_HOST="unix://$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/docker.sock"  # rootless
```

in [my local .envrc](https://direnv.net/).

The two daemons appear to work completely independently of each other as expected, i.e. image cache, running containers (`docker ps`), etc. are all separate.

Disclaimer: One thing I have yet to test are more elaborate container network setups, e.g. when running rootful & rootless `docker compose` in parallel. I usually don't do that, though, so for now I'm happy.

Comment: Hey balu, thanks for taking the time! I followed the same process you outlined a couple of days ago and got similar results. The rootless version performs about how i would expect except that I'm currently still unable to mount Nvidia GPUs into the rootless containers. 

'nvidia-container-cli: mount error: failed to add device rules: unable to find any existing device filters attached to the cgroup: bpf_prog_query(BPF_CGROUP_DEV ... running hook: exit status 1, stdout: , stderr: Auto-detected mode as 'legacy'
'

Unfortunately I haven't had the time to dig further into it.